# How to simulate the run button with a command line in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm working on a script using the PyAutoGUI module. Sometimes the script gets stuck in a while loop because it's looking for pictures/images that are not shown due to connection problems etc. If this happens I want the program to start again from zero, so I want to simulate the play/run-button in Pycharm with a command line. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

What it sounds like you want to do is restart your program if it doesnt respond. A similiar question appears to have been posted here: [Python help - Need the ability to restart the script when it hangs or automatically set a timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23897688/python-help-need-the-ability-to-restart-the-script-when-it-hangs-or-automatica) so I would reccommend having a look at that. Simulating the run button in Pycharm might seem like a good idea at first but it is very specific and a bad practice to simulate user actions like that unless there is absolutely no viable alternative.

Comment: Thanks, he wants to achieve exactly the same as me however there isn't a solution in that thread.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Patel I managed to solve my issue. You can use ctrl+f5 to restart a script so now when I'm stuck in a while loop I'm using this code:

```
        #Click toolbar Pycharm
        pyautogui.moveTo(1672,15,1)
        pyautogui.click()
        #Rerun the script
        pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl","f5")
```